# How to generate different pairs of unequal numbers?

Tags: c++

I want to create N different pairs and want the numbers in the pairs to be unequal. The numbers in the pairs are in the range from 0 to K - 1.

```
vector<pair<int, int> > p;
pair<int, int> temp;
int N = 8;
int K = 7;
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int f = random(0, K-1);
    int s = random(0, K-1);
    p.push_back({ f, s });
}
temp = p[c];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (temp != p[i]) {
        c++;
    }
    else {
        while (temp == p[i]) {
            temp.first = random(0, K - 1);
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

I want to have such pairs of numbers:
Output:
(0, 4)
(0, 3)
(1, 2)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 3)
(5, 3)
(5, 4)

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach: 
Put your number pairs in a `std::set` (which will eliminate duplicates). Keep generating pairs until the `.size()` of your set is your desired amount of unique pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Are `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` considered the same pair? Do you disallow pairs like `(a,a)`?

If so, here's a way to generate `N` distinct pairs from the numbers `0` through to `K`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::set<std::pair<int, int>> generate_pairs(int N, int K) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, K-1);

    std::set<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;
    int f, s;
    while (pairs.size() < N) {
        // Generate the first element of the pair.
        f = dis(gen);

        // Generate the second element of the pair.
        // This could be improved, but simply assures we don't get pairs (a,a).
        for (s = f; s == f; s = dis(gen));

        // Make sure we can't get both (f,s) and (s,f) in our set of pairs.
        pairs.emplace(std::make_pair(std::min(f, s), std::max(f, s)));
    }
    return pairs;
}

int main() {
    const auto pairs = generate_pairs(10,10);
    for (const auto p: pairs)
        std::cout << "(" << p.first << "," << p.second << ")\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::set` as your unique pairs container and use `std::pair` to represent your pairs. Then, you can enter a `while` loop that inserts random pairs into your set while its `.size() < N`. It's simpler and will yield a cleaner solution since `std::set` automatically handles duplicates by eliminating them. The code would look like this:

```
set<pair<int, int>> unique_pairs;

int a, b;
while (unique_pairs.size() < N)
{
    a = random(0, K - 1);
    b = random(0, K - 1);

    //Prevents sets like (a, a).
    while (a == b) b = random(0, K - 1);

    //Prevents sets like (a, b) and (b, a).
    unique_pairs.insert(make_pair(min(a, b), max(a, b)));
}
```

If you don't care for the order of your pairs inside the set, then you can use [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) instead of [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). Be sure to read the references as there are some differences you need to be aware of.

Comment: Couldn't the numbers in the pairs be equal in this approach? For example, in an iteration of the while loop, you generate 0 both times (i.e. pair (0,0), it seems like it violates the "want the numbers in the pairs to be unequal" requirement?

Comment: @Sebastian if you store the pair `0,0` into the set more than once, only a single pair will be stored. The `.size()` will not increase, so the loop will keep going until enough *unique* pairs have been generated. A `std::set` cannot store duplicates.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm aware of that. I think we have a miscommunication. I'm referring to the part of the question that says: "want the numbers in the pairs to be unequal." I think that the asker does not want to allow pairs like (0,0) (or any pair of the form (i,i) where the pair is a number repeated twice). I suspect he / she - as you can see from the examples provided - only wants pairs of the form (i,j) where i != j.

Comment: @Sebastian That's a fair point. I read the question as only disallowing unique pairs where a,b and b,a would be unique..

Comment: Sorry for meddling in @Sebastian and @JesperJuhl, just pointing out that the `while (a == b) b = random(0, K - 1);` prevents sets of the form `(i, i)`. At first I didn't checked those, but later I added it and a another check for permuted entries, so that the OP could choose in accordance to his/her needs.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz Yes, that's what I was doing with my `for (s = f; s == f; s = dis(gen));` in my answer below :-).